# Where can I find the old (free) version of Nik Collection?

Tags: photoshop, nik-software

I want to use the Nik collection for some editing I am doing. As I understand it, google made this collection free, and shortly after DxO bought it, it received some updates and a price tag of $70. The free trial would probably work, but it is not an ideal solution. Is there a place to find the older, free version of Nik collection? Also, would it even work with PS CC 2018?

Comment: Because the software is available from DxO, seeking to find where to find older or unsupported free versions is akin to being a "shopping" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded this free version at the time it was made available. I learned about it through the "Photo Rumors" website. It looks like the official download links listed in the article there are still live...

[Nik Collection now available for free | Photo Rumors](https://photorumors.com/2016/03/24/nik-collection-now-available-for-free/)

Answer (score 3):

Old version is available on numerous file download sites I wouldn't trust - but found you can still get it direct from DxO:

https://nikcollection.dxo.com/nik-collection-2012/

Answer (score 2):

There is a sad truth: If some company makes something freely available - unless it comes with a license that allows redistribution! - and ceases to do so, anything available on the internet after that time will be a bootleg copy in nature.

I am not commenting on the ethical issues/controversy.

Just be aware that sites where files that are legally in a gray or black area are offered, especially if that content seems to be monetized in any way (eg by banner ads), tend to be untrustworthy: Someone who doesn't respect intellectual property in order to profit from running such a site could *potentially* also be someone who doesn't respect the integrity of your computer or personal data if they can make a profit from not respecting it.

If nik (or a third party THEY (or a reputable publisher like a computer magazine) used to host their download link) still make it available for download even if it isn't advertised, that risk of course is not given. However, anything pointing to a generic file hosting service should be treated with suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Older Version](https://www.filehorse.com/download-nik-collection/old-versions/)

In general searching for "older version of *software* installer" or "version *x.x.xx* version of *software* installer" will get you what you are looking for. There are other, less reputable ways of getting that software too.

Comment: See my answer for why this is an idea to be considered with caution.